# .htaccess, adjusting the rewrite base, based on subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Having some trouble on Apache with an htaccess file.
I have one script that needs to be access from two different virtual subdirectories that are both pointed to the same place.

The problem is that when I set the rewrite base to one location, and try to access is from the other place, it has the wrong variables on it. Since it's a virtual directory, there's only one .htaccess file, so I need a way for my htaccess file to be aware of what directory it being called when it accesses the script, so that I can set the rewrite base in the script to the appropriate virtual directory.

I'm wracking my brain over this.
Here's the code I have that doesn't work.
I've tried a few variations, and I feel like I'm close, but I'm stumped.

```
            Options -Indexes
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            ErrorDocument 404 index.php

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
              RewriteEngine on

              RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} /$1 -f 
                RewriteBase /$1/


              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
              RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
            </IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Done. Edited to include the whole file.

Comment: I don't think its a working version of your .htaccess since RewriteBase is appearing after RewriteCont and using `$1`.

Comment: Right. That's what I'm trying to do. I need the base to be dynamic, based on the virtual directory it's in. Not setting the base reverts it to the wrong directory.

Comment: Try removing the RewriteBase entirely. I find it is not always necessary. You could also try setting `RewriteBase /` in the htaccess that is in the root, and not setting in it the subdir's htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to have RewriteBase pointed at root using `/`. Consider code like this in your root .htaccess under `$DOCUMENT_DIR`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 index.php

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(?:vdir1|vdir2)/(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Here vdir1 and vdir2 are your 2 virtual directories.